# Group Customers by Status in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
customer_id mis_date  status
----------------------------
 10003       2014-01-01  1   
 10003       2014-01-02  1    
 10003       2014-01-03  0   
 10003       2014-01-04  0   
 10003       2014-01-05  0   
 10003       2014-01-06  1   
 10003       2014-01-07  1    
 10003       2014-01-08  1    
 10003       2014-01-09  1    
 10003       2014-01-10  0   
 10003       2014-01-11  0   
 10003       2014-01-12  0   
 10003       2014-01-13  1     
 10003       2014-01-14  1     
 10003       2014-01-15  1
```

I'm trying to build the "group" column:

```
customer_id mis_date status group
----------------------------------
 10003       2014-01-01  1    1
 10003       2014-01-02  1    1
 10003       2014-01-03  0   NULL
 10003       2014-01-04  0   NULL
 10003       2014-01-05  0   NULL
 10003       2014-01-06  1    2
 10003       2014-01-07  1    2
 10003       2014-01-08  1    2
 10003       2014-01-09  1    2
 10003       2014-01-10  0   NULL
 10003       2014-01-11  0   NULL
 10003       2014-01-12  0   NULL
 10003       2014-01-13  1     3
 10003       2014-01-14  1     3
 10003       2014-01-15  1     3
```

Does anyone know how I can build this group column?

The logic: each day I'm tracking after the customer status and I want to know in each day what is the number of times that that status happened in the customer history but only when he is in the status.

For example: first_time - 1, second_time - 2 etc.

I am kicking my head off and can't find a solution. I guess it's not so complex.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you want a partition, not a group

Comment: I think this is the expected result, we need to know actual data and logic behind it

Comment: I've edit my post.

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT customer_id, mis_date, status,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY mis_date) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, status ORDER BY mis_date) AS grp
   FROM mytable
), CTE2 AS (
   SELECT customer_id, status, grp, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(mis_date)) AS rn
   FROM CTE
   WHERE status = 1
   GROUP BY customer_id, status, grp 
)
SELECT c.customer_id, c.mis_date, c.status, rn       
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN CTE2 c2 
   ON c.customer_id = c2.customer_id AND c.status = c2.status AND c.grp = c2.grp
ORDER BY mis_date
```

`CTE` identifies islands of consecutive records having the same `status` value. `CTE2` enumerates `status = 1` subgroups.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach of doing it without `CTE` is like following query.

```
SELECT customer_id, mis_date, status, 
       CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY rc) END grp 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               (SELECT CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 0 
                         ELSE (SELECT Count(status)  FROM   table1 t2 
                               WHERE  t2.mis_date <= t1.mis_date AND status = 0) END grp)rc 
        FROM   table1 t1) t2 
ORDER  BY mis_date
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| customer_id | mis_date                | status | grp  |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 1    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 1    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 0      | NULL |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 0      | NULL |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 0      | NULL |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 2    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 2    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 2    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-09 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 2    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 | 0      | NULL |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 0      | NULL |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-12 00:00:00.000 | 0      | NULL |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-13 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 3    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-14 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 3    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
| 10003       | 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 3    |
+-------------+-------------------------+--------+------+
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/HQFQ85147)

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution please. This adds grouping as per your need

```
 with cte0 as 
 ( 
   select [customer_id], [mis_date], [status],
     COALESCE(LAG(status) over (order by mis_date), status) oldstatus
   FRom Table1
 ),
 cte1 as ( 
   select cte0.*, 
     case when status = 0 then 
       null 
     else
       COUNT( case when  status != oldStatus and status = 0 then 1  else null end) OVER (ORDER BY mis_date) 
     end + 1 grp
   from cte0
 )
 select * from cte1
 GO
```

```
 customer_id | mis_date            | status | oldstatus |  grp
 ----------: | :------------------ | -----: | --------: | ---:
       10003 | 01/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    1
       10003 | 02/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    1
       10003 | 03/01/2014 00:00:00 |      0 |         1 | null
       10003 | 04/01/2014 00:00:00 |      0 |         0 | null
       10003 | 05/01/2014 00:00:00 |      0 |         0 | null
       10003 | 06/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         0 |    2
       10003 | 07/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    2
       10003 | 08/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    2
       10003 | 09/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    2
       10003 | 10/01/2014 00:00:00 |      0 |         1 | null
       10003 | 11/01/2014 00:00:00 |      0 |         0 | null
       10003 | 12/01/2014 00:00:00 |      0 |         0 | null
       10003 | 13/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         0 |    3
       10003 | 14/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    3
       10003 | 15/01/2014 00:00:00 |      1 |         1 |    3
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b6a66480f7b5dfc6e7db372f3e3d478)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ALTER TABLE statement in SQL Server to add a column to a table.
Syntax

The syntax to add a column in a table in SQL Server (Transact-SQL) is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name column_definition;
```

Let's look at an example that shows how to add a column in an SQL Server table using the ALTER TABLE statement.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE customer
  ADD group VARCHAR(10);
```

This SQL Server ALTER TABLE example will add a column to the customer table called group.

Comment: Thank's but you missed understood me. I want to generate the values in the column.

Comment: Can't understand, could you please explain more

Answer (score 1):

You can identify each group of "1" by the number of non-zero statuses before them.  If you don't care that the group numbers are sequential:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 1
             then sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id order by mis_date)
        end) as grp
from t;
```

No subqueries, joins or aggregation.

However, you probably want the numbers sequential (as in your example).  For that, a subquery is needed:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 1
             then dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by grp1)
        end) as grp
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer_id order by  mis_date) as grp1
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: just as FYI,  I think there are some syntax error partition by order by customer_id mis_date